# SQL - Joining 2 tables, show all from tbl1 and data from tbl2 depending on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to show a full list of all users in my DB aswell as extra information from a second table depending on whether they have a record in the second table

Im using MySQL, ive tried a few left join/right join union combos but nothing i have works

```sql
SELECT users.id, users.name, success.URL_ID, success.docreqid FROM users
LEFT JOIN success ON users.id = success.userid
where docreqid IS NULL
union
SELECT users.id, users.name, success.URL_ID, success.docreqid FROM users
RIGHT JOIN success ON users.id = success.userid
where docreqid = 1;
```

I have a small table of 10 users. Only one user in my db has a record in the success tbl against docreqid '1'.
I want a table of ALL users and the URL_ID for their form if they have submitted it.

The above code works perfectly for this.

If i change the last line to:

```
where docreqid = 2;
```

I only get 9 results (the user with a record for docreqid '1' is missing).

I would like this table to show all 10 users and 'NULL' in the URL_ID & docreqid columns until they have completed the required action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `left join` should do what you want:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, s.URL_ID, s.docreqid
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     success s
     ON u.id = s.userid AND s.docreqid = 1;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` returns all rows in the first table -- no `WHERE` is filtering results.  The `ON` only matches rows in `success` that meet the additional condition in the `ON` clause.